# How to return a custom list of Model objects using Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query my application's models. I'm following the instructions [**here**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#testing-our-api).

My Model looks like this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

My Route looks like this in myApp's url.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsViewSet)
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
    fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

My Viewset looks like this:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def retrieve(self,request,pk=None):
        queryset = MyObjects.objects.get(pk=pk).customMyObjectList()

        if not queryset:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer = MyObjectSerializer(queryset)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I hit /api/myObjects/60/ I get the following error:

```
`base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.model` or `.queryset` attribute.
```

[**This**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers) says that I need a base_name parameter on my route. But from the docs, it is unclear to me what that value of that base_name parameter should be. Can someone please tell me what the route should look like with the base_name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a Django REST-Api that returns a custom list of models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108636/how-to-build-a-django-rest-api-that-returns-a-custom-list-of-models)

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewset` is missing a `.queryset` or `.model` property. `DefaultRouter()` introspects one of these properties to determine the url path.

You can optionally define `base_name` when creating `DefaultRouter()`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('myObjects', views.MyObjectsViewSet, 'base-name-here')
```

Comment: Can I put anyhting in the base_name? what should its value be? Can I put a random string? The whole point of my question is what is the point of this base_name and what does it do? How does it work?

Comment: I'm not able to explain it any better than the documentation you've linked to.

Comment: So in this case. what is the correct value of base_name?

Comment: Why not just define a model on your viewset and then you won't have to worry about base_name.