# Is there a default Django/Rest serializer for a single integer?

Tags: python, django, rest

Using the Django-Rest-Framework, I have successfully built APIs that return my application's models. You can see the models, viewsets, serializers etc [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108636/how-to-build-a-django-rest-api-that-returns-a-custom-list-of-models).

Now I want to create another, much simpler API. This api will not return a list of model objects. Instead it will return a single integer. So the viewset will looks something like this:

```
class MyObjectCount(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def retrieve(self,request,pk=None):
        queryset = 21
        serializer = IntegerSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

But I don't know what Integer Serializer should look like. Or maybe I don't need to write my own IntegerSerializer but can instead can use some default serializer for such cases.
Can someone please recommend the best solution?

Comment: What are you serializing it as?

Comment: Right now I am not serializing it at all. IntegerSerializer() is not written. I need to serialize it as a JSON object. But I don't know what IntegerSerializer should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You only need serializers for Django model objects because standard per-format libraries don't know how to handle Django objects. 'Primitive' Python native types *are* understood, just return those natively and have the Django Rest framework take care of turning that into JSON for you (based on content negotiation.

```
return Response(queryset)
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in this answer. You assign to the variable data, but then you never use it in the next line.

Comment: This did not work. When I point my browser to http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/myObjects/60/ (as I pointed to at the top of this post) I get the my custom list of objects successfully. However, when I try to do the same for http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/myObjectsCount/60/, (Which I have coded as u suggested above) the resonse is text-based listing of the source code of the page.

Comment: That makes no sense; the view returns a `json.dumps()` result; nowhere is there a page being returned.

Comment: Martijn, This works better: return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK). I hope you don't mind that I edited your answer.

Comment: @SaqibAli: The *default* status is 200 OK. Setting it explicitly should make no difference. The only difference then is that I set the content type explicitly, overriding content negotiation. I've updated the answer, because I see that Django-Rest will encode to JSON for you already *anyway*, based on content-negotiation.

Comment: Ok, but "application/json" was the problem. That was causing the behavior I described above.

Comment: Exactly. And note that the answer is much simpler here; just return `Response(queryset)`, where `queryset` is your integer value.